# Inconsistent escaping in Ansible

Tags: yaml, ansible

Consider the following Ansible playbook:

```
- name: Dump
  hosts: test
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Dump1
      debug:
        var: "{{ 'foo-123-far'| regex_replace('^foo-([0-9]+).*$', '\\\\1') }}"
    - name: Dump2
      debug: var="{{ 'foo-123-far'| regex_replace('^foo-([0-9]+).*$', '\\1') }}"
```

This produces the following output:

```
TASK: [Dump1] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "123": "123"
    }
}

TASK: [Dump2] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "123": "123"
    }
}
```

Why must one escape `\1` with `\\\\1` in Dump1 where I don't use the magical key=value arguments, but `\\1` suffices in the second?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case (`var:` on its own line), Ansible has to treat quoting specially to avoid the problematic combo of `: {{`, so it may have a particular treatment of the line in a parsing phase.

The second case doesn’t actually need the double-quotes, so Ansible may remove them earlier and subsequently treat the line differently.

There is [a note here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html) that states the case you’re hitting:

> If “regex_replace” filter is used with variables inside YAML arguments (as opposed to simpler ‘key=value’ arguments), then you need to escape backreferences (e.g. \1) with 4 backslashes (\\) instead of 2 (\).

Comment: I have seen that comment, and that's how I came to the idea of trying it out, even *without* using variables. I am puzzled that I have to use this kind of escaping.